# Shell script to unzip a file with a password

Tags: command-line, scripts, unzip

I am trying to unzip a file with a given password from the vendor. I need to automate this process so I'd like a command to do it, so that I can write a script.

Comment: Try this: `unzip  -P password file.zip`

Answer (score 14):

To unzip files with password use the `-P` option:

```
unzip -P password file.zip
```

To create a directory with same structure as the source `.zip` and place contents in it:

```
unzip -P password file.zip

# output
total 560
drwxrwxr-x   2 george george   4096 Mar  3 14:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 199 george george  12288 Mar  3 14:01 ../
drwx------   2 george george   4096 Apr 23  2016 file/
-rw-rw-r--   1 george george 150058 Feb 18 07:00 file.zip
```

To unzip content into current directory without creating one with same structure as source `.zip` file:

```
unzip -j -P password file.zip

# output
total 560
drwxrwxr-x   2 george george   4096 Mar  3 14:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 199 george george  12288 Mar  3 14:01 ../    
-rw-rw-r--   1 george george 150058 Feb 18 07:00 file.zip
-rw-------   1 george george 405115 Apr 23  2016 Transcript.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an `unsupported compression method 99` error, then your ZIP file is AES encrypted which is *currently* not supported by `unzip`. Use 7zip instead (install with `sudo apt install p7zip-full`):

```
7za x -p<PASSWORD> file.zip
```